# Trust anchor for certification path not found due to missing intermediate/chain certificate

Tags: java, android, ssl

This is the exception I get in Java,

```
java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
```

I've checked out the android documentation and several answers on StackOverflow, and figured out that I'm facing this issue because the server I make requests to doesn't have an intermediate/chain certificate.

One solution I found was to implement a [`TrustManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/javax/net/ssl/TrustManager) that does nothing, which works great but is obviously something I don't want to use in production.

Another solution I found was to concatenate the site certificate with the intermediate ones. This seems to be the ideal solution, however I only make requests to this server and don't have access to it. Is there any other way to resolve this issue?

Comment: You should inform the admins of the server that they are not operating it correctly.  According to the [RFC for TLS](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5246#section-7.4.2), the server MUST send all the intermediate CA certificates as part of the handshake.

Comment: @garethTheRed I tried, they ignored me . This is actually my university's site.

Comment: That's rather worrying. If you're studying IT, I suggest you find a better university ;-)

Comment: @garethTheRed I am lol 